# Android: My GPS application desn't display my correct location on the Google maps ? why?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I'm using GPS to get my location but this code shows my location in Pacific although I'm in middle east ...

another functionality of this code is to add an icon ( marker ) in the place I touch on the screen , according my code, does it works fine ?!

here is my code :

```
package com.adhamenaya.android;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

public class MapApp extends MapActivity {

    private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mapController;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private GeoPoint p;
    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays ;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initLayout();
        initMap();
        listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();        
    }

    private void initLayout(){
         mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

    }
    private void initMap(){
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setStreetView(true);
        mapController=mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(10);// 1 is world view
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0, 0, new GeoUpdateHandler());

    }      
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
    {
        private GeoPoint p;
        private int res;

        public MapOverlay(GeoPoint p,int res){
            this.p=p;
            this.res=res;
        }

    @Override
     public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) 
     {
         super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

         //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
         Point screenPts = new Point();
         mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

         //---add the marker---
         Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),res);            
         canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-20, null);         
         return true;
     }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) 
        {   
            //---when user lifts his finger---
            if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
                 GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY());
                 mapController.animateTo(p);
                 MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(p,R.drawable.redicon);
                 listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);        
                 mapView.invalidate();
            }                            
            return false;
        }        
    }

    class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            int lat=(int)(location.getLatitude()*1E6);
            int lng=(int)(location.getLongitude()*1E6);         
            GeoPoint p=new GeoPoint(lat,lng);
            mapController.animateTo(p);
            MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(p,R.drawable.blueicon);
            listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);        
            mapView.invalidate();

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

}

}
```

Comment: Have you verified that your coordinates are the correct values, in the correct units?

Comment: @Sherif In fact it worked well on emulator, but didn't on A real device !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try running it on an actual device or just the Emulator? I had experienced the same issue, the location co-ordinates are updated using the ISP's IP address in case GPS isn't available such as in case of emulator. There age high chances the code will run fine on a device.

Comment: In fact it worked well on emulator, but didn't on A real device !!

Comment: does the GPS show proper location in the other applications(like google maps) on the device?